# SSIS and Normalizing Data in TXT file

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis

I'm learning SSIS and I have a question about how to normalize existing data in a text file.

In my directory I have a text file for each state in the United States so AK.txt and AL.txt has the following structure:

`AK,F,1910,Mary,14`
`AL,F,1910,Mary,875`

This stands for `state,sex,year,name,frequency`

If I have the following tables:

- State(id,state)
- Sex(id,sex)
- Year(id,year)
- Name(id,name,frequency)

What transformation in SSIS would I use to put each data element in it's respective table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. To firstly capture the multiple files, here are two options:

1. Use a For Each File iterator to loop through each file and load into something (a rowset object , a raw file or a staging table), then use that as a source for part B
2. Alternatively create an flat file source for each file and join them up with a union operator (not recommended)

B. To get that single data flow into multiple tables

Use a multicast to cast the data out to 5 streams. Then order and distinct them to get distinct records then load them into the tables.

My personal preference is to load into a staging table and do everything via SQL after that.

Comment: Does the Multicast transformation work on the column level? For instance, if I want to move the state to a table and the other fields to their respective tables. Can that be done?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see. Multicast makes a copy of data. You'll need 5 copies which you then need to 'distinct' on each column. Then you end up with a data stream to put into a table. I'm curious as to why you are throwing away the State, Sex, Year info against the frequency figure. i.e. after you load this data you can't analyse your frequency based on Year from your `Name` table.

Comment: To put it another way, `Multicast` makes a copy of the data. After the multicast you need to use a `Sort` to convert the first multicast into distinct State records then load that into your State table. So on for the others. But if you ask me it's oh so much eaasier in SQL

Comment: Interesting. After all of your help, I'm thinking this may be easier to do in SQL.

Comment: Im my opinion: It is definitely easier in SQL. Iterate through the files using SSIS and load them all into a single staging table. Then just run some INSERT/SELECT DISTINCT's to load your tables from the staging table. I find SSIS is good at orchestrating stuff but not so good at doing complex data stuff.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a place to began researching. Googling "staging table in ssis" really has helped me set afoot with this technology.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is `comma` delimited "state,sex,year.." easiest way is to use the *flat file* source. You can set it up to use a comma as a column delimiter and a newline as a row delimiter. Make sure to set the right datatypes under *advanced* as well. The output is then a column for each delimited field. Then use one of the destinations(OLE DB..) and put the stuff in yout tables.

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions